# What is a balcony on the top floor or the rooftop of a building called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, vocabulary

I know a room or an apartment on the top floor or on the rooftop can be called an attic or a penthouse depending on the room or the apartment. I wonder what a balcony on the rooftop or on the top floor would be called in English. I am talking about a balcony like the ones in the pictures below. Are either of these phrases usable: *"Rooftop terrace"* or *"Rooftop deck"*?

[image] [image]

Comment: We don't usually have such things in Britain, because it rains so much. But I'd probably call it a ***roof garden***.

Comment: **Roof garden** if it has plants, otherwise **rooftop terrace**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.